# Remove anti-aliasing from an image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library, antialiasing

I want to remove the antialiasing from an image. This code will get the 4 major colors from an image, compare each pixel to the 4 major colors and assign the closest color.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('pattern_2.png')
image_nd = np.array(image)
image_colors = {}

for row in image_nd:
    for pxl in row:
        pxl = tuple(pxl)
        if not image_colors.get(pxl):
            image_colors[pxl] = 1
        else:
            image_colors[pxl] += 1

sorted_image_colors = sorted(image_colors, key=image_colors.get, reverse=True)
four_major_colors = sorted_image_colors[:4]


def closest(colors, color):
    colors = np.array(colors)
    color = np.array(color)
    distances = np.sqrt(np.sum((colors - color) ** 2, axis=1))
    index_of_smallest = np.where(distances == np.amin(distances))
    smallest_distance = colors[index_of_smallest]
    return smallest_distance[0]


for y, row in enumerate(image_nd):
    for x, pxl in enumerate(row):
        image_nd[y, x] = closest(four_major_colors, image_nd[y, x])

aliased = Image.fromarray(image_nd)
aliased.save("pattern_2_al.png")
```

This is the result:
[image]

As you can see, the borders between colors aren't perfect.

And this is the result I'm after:

[image]

(it seems the image hosting site compresses the image, and won't show "aliased" image properly)

Comment: @HansHirse is probably right; I didn't consider this aspect and checked most of what comes after ;-)  I would like to point out two aspects:  ① Your way of determining the four main colors will only work for a specific set of images without many intermediate colors and without dithering of the large areas (JPG artifacts and similar), but maybe your input fits these characteristics.  ② If main color A is close to the line between main colors B and C, your algorithm will choose A for an anti-alias pixel between B and C. You could fix that by using neighbor pixels instead of a simple color match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem here is located in your `closest` method:

```py
def closest(colors, color):
    colors = np.array(colors)
    color = np.array(color)
    distances = np.sqrt(np.sum((colors - color) ** 2, axis=1))
```

Both `colors` and `color` become NumPy arrays of type `uint8`. Now, when subtracting `uint8` values, you won't get negative values, but integer underflow will happen, resulting in values near `255`. Therefore, the then calculated `distances` are wrong, which finally leads to the wrong color picking.

So, the fastest fix would be to cast both variables to `int32`:

```py
def closest(colors, color):
    colors = np.array(colors).astype(np.int32)
    color = np.array(color).astype(np.int32)
    distances = np.sqrt(np.sum((colors - color) ** 2, axis=1))
```

Also, it might be useful to make use of NumPy's vectorization power. Consider the following approach for your `closest` method:

```py
def closest(colors, image):
    colors = np.array(colors).astype(np.int32)
    image = image.astype(np.int32)
    distances = np.argmin(np.array([np.sqrt(np.sum((color - image) ** 2, axis=2)) for color in colors]), axis=0)
    return colors[distances].astype(np.uint8)
```

So, instead of iterating all the pixels with

```py
for y in np.arange(image_nd.shape[0]):
    for x in np.arange(image_nd.shape[1]):
        image_nd[y, x] = closest(four_major_colors, image_nd[y, x])
```

you can simply pass the whole image:

```py
image_nd = closest(four_major_colors, image_nd)
```

Using the given image, I get a speed-up of 100x on my machine. Surely, finding the RGB histogram values can also be optimized. (Unfortunately, my experience with Python dictionaries isn't yet that great...)

Anyway – hope that helps!

Comment: I don't why I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot handle this data type` when converting the return value of your `closest()` method.

Comment: Sorry, I just found out `Image.fromarray()` expects `uint8`

Comment: @conquistador That's an actual error from me, the conversion back to `uint8` was supposed to be there. I edited my answer, and fixed that issue. Sorry for that.

Comment: You can omit the `np.sqrt()` since a < b if a^2 < b^2 and make it (maybe marginally) faster.

Answer (score 1):

Since your test image mostly contains blocks of identical colours, you might try applying a "mode" image filter, which chooses the most frequent colour in an NxN box around each pixel:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

image = Image.open('pattern_2.png')
print(f'Original has {len(image.getcolors(1024))} colours')

aliased = image.filter(ImageFilter.ModeFilter(5))
aliased.save('pattern_2_al.png')
print(f'Aliased has {len(aliased.getcolors(1024))} colours')
```

```
$ ./test.py 
Original has 678 colours
Aliased has 10 colours
```

[image: combined result]

I found that a 5x5 box worked well for my own test image, and reasonably well for yours, but you might want to play around with the box size (note that the larger the box, the more rounded your "aliased" result will be).

The results aren't perfect (it produced an image with 10 not 4 colours), but you may also find that applying the image filter before running your own algorithm gives you good results.

See [Pillow documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageFilter.html#PIL.ImageFilter.ModeFilter) for details.