# svglib - why are hundreds of additional colours being added when converting a two-colour SVG to PNG?

Tags: python, svg, reportlab

When I use [svglib](https://github.com/deeplook/svglib) to convert a [two-colour SVG](https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/openweb.svg) to PNG, why does the [resulting PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81wX2.png) contain 316 colours?

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPM

drawing = svg2rlg("openweb.svg")
renderPM.drawToFile(drawing, "converted_file.png", fmt="PNG", dpi=72)
```

The number of colours is confirmed using `cv2` and `numpy`:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(png_file, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)  # Read PNG file
colours = img.reshape(-1, img.shape[2])  # Get colours
unique_colours = np.unique(colours, axis=0)  # Get unique colours
print('\nPNG colour count:\n ', len(unique_colours))
```

Which outputs:

```
PNG colour count:
  316
```

Here is the code for the [original SVG file](https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/openweb.svg), which contains 2 colours:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 84 118">
  <path d="M62,3c0,45,55,78-21,114c-5-40-80-61,21-114" fill="#5e962d"/>
  <path d="M17,15c6,35-52,65,24,102c50-37,46-80-24-102" fill="#8ad945"/>
</svg>
```

And here is the png file, which contains 316 colours:

[image]

Comparison of SVG vs PNG:

[image]

Zoomed in, notice how additional shades of green are added at edges:

[image]

These additonal colours are confirmed using Photoshop's histogram:

[image]

At what point in `svglib` or `renderPM` do these additional colours get added, and can this behaviour be overriden so that the PNG colours match that of the SVG (i.e. 2 colours + background)?

Comment: please post such a picture and also the source svg file.

Comment: I've updated the question to include photos and original SVG file

Comment: yes, that is antialiasing, i.e. svglib spends more effort to draw a better picture. I am not familiar with svglib or advanced svg features, but maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161624/how-to-render-svg-elements-with-crisp-edges-while-still-keeping-anti-aliasing

Comment: Thanks. After further investigation it looks like antialiasing can't be turned off in svglib. My understanding is that the problem of antialiasing can't be solved in python without building a rendering engine from scratch.

Comment: did you check the link I gave? it talks about a `shape-rendering` property that might affect this

Comment: I did, it seems like the handling of `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` is dependent on the rendering engine. It works fine for Firefox, Chrome etc, however unfortunately it looks like `svglib` uses `libart` for rendering which ignores `shape-rendering`. I've tried adding `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` at the root, in the path, and both, and still no luck. From what I've read, I believe Inkscape and other python SVG libraries such as Cairo also don't offer this functionality since I imagine they are based on the same underlying rendering engine.

Comment: As a workaround, massively increasing the resolution when saving to PNG, then deleting any pixels which are not in the desired colours, provides a good approximation, with the greater the resolution, the better the approximation.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with the libraries involved, but the obvious guess would be that whatever step that does the conversion from vector to raster format (probably renderPM.drawToFile) performs antialiasing, i.e. reducing the "jaggedness" of diagonal edges by adding, for example, grey pixels along the edges of a black line on a white background.

Comment: I've updated my question to include a zoomed-in PNG. It does appear that antialiasing is taking place. I thought it was happening somewhere in `renderPM.drawToFile`, however I can't find any code in `renderPM.drawToFile` which seems to handle this 'blending' of colours. Similarly I can't find anything obvious in `svglib`. I'm very puzzled. I'm hoping that if I can find out exactly where this antialiasing takes place, then the behaviour can be manipulated. Or perhaps it's as simple as passing an argument such as `aa=off` during the conversion process, however I can't find any documentation.

Comment: It looks like reportlab uses [libart](https://www.levien.com/libart/) for rendering, and like libart has no way of turning off antialiasing, but I could be wrong about that...

Comment: It looks like you're right. After further research, I don't believe it is possible to convert an SVG into an aliased PNG image in python using an existing rendering engine. So instead of building my own rendering engin, I've decided to approximate the antialiased pixels using closest neighbour method to condense to a finite number of colour . Here is the code if anyone's interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59104242/remove-anti-aliasing-from-an-image. It's not perfect and often approximates to the wrong colour, however is a workaround I found useful.